# iOS MapView goes under navigation bar, status bar, and tab bar controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mapkit

I have a ViewController with a navigation controller and a tab bar controller. This ViewController has 2 buttons that toggle the visibility of a scroll view and a map view. The main thing is to have these 2 buttons always show up in the same place regardless of orientation or the view that happens to be visible.

The problem I am having is that the MapView won't size properly. If I just give it a frame from self.view.bounds it goes under the navigation bar / tab bar - basically taking up the whole screen. This throws off the location of my toggle buttons.

I noticed my ScrollView does the same (using a background color and a translucent navigation bar) but the positioning of sub views on it stay within the visible area (between the navigation bar and the tab bar). So when I add my toggle buttons, they show in the correct place.

When I press the toggle buttons, I just re-assign the parent view of the buttons to the now displayed view (ScrollView or MapView). This always works on the scroll view but due to the positioning, they end up going under the navigation bar when the MapView is displayed.

I have tried creating the frame for the MapView manually but I get odd results. I use this for the frame:

```
CGRect mapFrame = CGRectMake(
    0,
    (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height),
    self.view.frame.size.width,
    (
     self.view.frame.size.height
     - (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height + self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height)
    )
);
```

I then set the auto resizing masks

```
[self.mapView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
```

But with this, if I enter into the view controller in landscape mode - the MapView is off the screen. If I enter in portrait mode and then rotate to landscape, the top margin is off but about 10 points so it still goes under the navigation bar a bit (and has a visible margin between the tab bar and the bottom of the map view).

How can I make the MapView subviews only display within the visible region like the ScrollView does? I don't mind so much if the map itself goes under the navigation bar / tab bar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ugh, I found the answer just a few minutes ago. I have no idea why this is the default behavior on iOS 7 but alas, there it is.

The solution is to add this to the viewDidLoad on the ViewController

```
[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
```

Much thanks [to the post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502135/navigation-controller-is-rendered-over-the-view-i-navigated-to)

Comment: You should mark this as the answer too.  :)  Thanks for the help.